# Millisecond is not removed from data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime-format

I have a `DateTime` column in my table. I want to store RUN date without millisecond stamp.
I tried below code, but in table, millisecond comes as 0000000.

Is that possible to store only date in "2021-06-09 08:58:03" format?

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use `smalldatetime` as your column data type if you don't required the millisecond

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Dates are not stored in any format, well an internal binary format only, they are stored as a date object. Formatting **ONLY** occurs when you display the date. When you query it you will be shown a default format, but that is not how it is stored. Note its recommended best practice to no longer use `smalldatetime` instead use `datetime2()`. I suggest storing as `datetime2()` and formatting to remove ms when you display it.

Comment: @Squirrel `smalldatetime` data type I believe is to the minute, not second? Also, unlike other times, I believe it is 'rounded to the nearest minute' rather than simply truncated.

Comment: my mistake. @seanb is correct. `smalldatetime` is up to minute only

Comment: @Sarat if you use SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 20) AS 'Result'; and store data in db. you will be able to retrieve the date without milliseconds

Comment: @Gudwlk isn't that just converting it to text?

Comment: Use `datetime2` with no fractional seconds.

Comment: @Gudwlk That won't work real well if your DATEFORMAT is YDM.

Comment: @Squirrel i tried with Smalldatetime, it is working as seanb said. minute is rounded and second ias always 00. Is that possible to save exact data from code (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Already alluded to above but use `datetime2(0)` if you only want precision to the second the value in the brackets is the number of decimal places to preserve for seconds. Zero in this case

Answer (score 0):

**Upfront**

1. Decide if you want to store a SQL `datetime` (or related) type or just a formatted string representation of a date and time.
2. Also decide if you want to use a local clock (of client workstation or even web server, with a clock that may be in a time zone different from your database server or maybe just out of time-sync with the database server).

**Because**

If the need is to be able to audit/report/coordinate the "order of events" you should choose an appropriate SQL type like `datetime`/`datetime2`/`smalldatetime` and instead of using client-side code to query the client-side clock, use SQL DATE and TIME functions [MS T-SQL date and time types and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  If you do this then record values at whatever precision they are offered and worry about string formatting when values are retrieved for display.

Only if you wish to *store* a string representation of a date and time in the database should you concern yourself with format at the time of insertion.

**Final Answer**

Consider a floating point numeric type like C#'s `double`.  You can declare `double d1 = 1.23E+2;` or `double d2 = 123`.  Both `d1` and `d2` contain an equal value (approximately 123.00...0 *with about 13 zeroes all of which are significant*). The format used at the time of assignment cannot influence future use of the value or system behaviour when it is used, whether for arithmetic or display purposes.  The same applies to date and time types.

**@mjwills comment taught me something I wasn't aware of: datetime2(0) seems to offer what you want - date and time with a precision of whole seconds, however fractions of a second are still recorded (try insert value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to a `datetime2(0)` column), so treat the precision parameter as a storage-allocation hint rather than a hard limit on "significant digits recorded" and you will still need to worry about formatting values when retrieved for reporting/display.**

Comment: Gentle suggestion: To reduce confusion you might want to use "date/time" rather than "timestamp" (noun) in your explanation. (The verb is a bit harder, e.g. "log current date/time".) In SQL Server, unlike ISO standards, `timestamp` is a synonym for [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "`timestamp` is the synonym for the `rowversion` data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use `rowversion` instead of `timestamp` wherever possible. "